# Kerberos credentials cache reported differently in Debian Squeeze and Debian Wheezy

Tags: locale, kerberos

I have two debian servers which use same LDAP/Kerberos server, but dates in output of klist on them shown in different format - m/d/Y on squeeze vs d/m/Y on wheezy.

Is there a way to change it on wheezy to m/d/Y format as well?

Locale settings - Squeeze

```
user@squeeze:~ > locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
user@squeeze:~ > locale -ck LC_TIME
LC_TIME
abday="Sun;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat"
day="Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday"
abmon="Jan;Feb;Mar;Apr;May;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Oct;Nov;Dec"
mon="January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December"
am_pm="AM;PM"
d_t_fmt="%a %d %b %Y %r %Z"
d_fmt="%m/%d/%Y"
t_fmt="%r"
t_fmt_ampm="%I:%M:%S %p"
era=
era_year=""
era_d_fmt=""
alt_digits=
era_d_t_fmt=""
era_t_fmt=""
time-era-num-entries=0
time-era-entries="S"
week-ndays=7
week-1stday=19971130
week-1stweek=7
first_weekday=1
first_workday=2
cal_direction=1
timezone=""
date_fmt="%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
time-codeset="UTF-8"
```

Locale settings - wheezy

```
user@wheezy:~ > locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
user@wheezy:~ > locale -ck LC_TIME
LC_TIME
abday="Sun;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;Sat"
day="Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday"
abmon="Jan;Feb;Mar;Apr;May;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Oct;Nov;Dec"
mon="January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December"
am_pm="AM;PM"
d_t_fmt="%a %d %b %Y %r %Z"
d_fmt="%m/%d/%Y"
t_fmt="%r"
t_fmt_ampm="%I:%M:%S %p"
era=
era_year=""
era_d_fmt=""
alt_digits=
era_d_t_fmt=""
era_t_fmt=""
time-era-num-entries=0
time-era-entries="S"
week-ndays=7
week-1stday=19971130
week-1stweek=7
first_weekday=1
first_workday=2
cal_direction=1
timezone=""
date_fmt="%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
time-codeset="UTF-8"
```

As you can see, until now all the same and locale settings seems to be similiar.

But on Squeeze:

```
user@squeeze:~ > klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1036_sTiFu16216
Default principal: user@domain

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
06/01/14 15:27:17  06/08/14 15:27:13  krbtgt/domain
```

while on Wheezy I get:

```
user@wheezy:~ > klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1036_W4vFn5D3Cr
Default principal: user@domain

Valid starting    Expires           Service principal
01/06/2014 15:28  08/06/2014 15:28  krbtgt/domain
```